# Lexer definition to match keyword or an abbreviation

Tags: antlr4

For writing a parser I would like to not only match full keywords but also abbreviations thereof, for example

MY-KEYWORD

must at least match

MY-KEY

but also any exact match longer than that, namely

MY-KEYW or MY-KEYWO or MY-KEYWOR or the full MY-KEYWORD

Is this possible with a reasonable lexer fragment or will I have to define specific alternative matches ?

TIA

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to do something like this:

```
MY_KEYWORD
 : 'MY-KEY' ('W' ('O' ('R' 'D'?)?)?)?
 ;
```